# Example of an indivisible stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

This question arises from pages 14 and 15 of [this review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.01894) on quantum stochastic processes (in a section on classical stochastic processes).

Suppose we have a stochastic process, with statistical states $\mathbb P(X_t)$ at each $t \in \mathcal T$ (say in a $d$-dimensional system, i.e. an observation at each time has $d$ possible outcomes $\{x_1, \dots, x_d\}$, e.g. rolling a die repeatedly would be 6-dimensional). So $\mathbb P(X_t)$ is a $d$-dimensional vector, perhaps of the form $(\mathbb P(X_t = x_1), \dots , \mathbb P(X_t = x_d))^T$.

Then a stochastic matrix $\Gamma_{t':t}$ would map the state $\mathbb P(X_t)$ to a later state $\mathbb P(X_{t'})$. The paper states in Eq. 38 that a *divisible process* is one where the following condition is satisfied:
$$
\Gamma_{t:r} = \Gamma_{t:s} \Gamma_{s:r} \quad \forall t > s > r.
$$

**Question 1.** What is the form of $\Gamma_{t':t}$? Presumably they must be $d  \times d$ matrices, possibly of the form
$$
\Gamma_{t':t} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb P(X_{t'} = x_1 | X_t = x_1) & P(X_{t'} = x_1 | X_t = x_2) & \cdots & P(X_{t'} = x_1 | X_t = x_d) \\
P(X_{t'} = x_2 | X_t = x_1) & P(X_{t'} = x_2 | X_t = x_2) & \cdots & P(X_{t'} = x_2 | X_t = x_d) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
P(X_{t'} = x_d | X_t = x_1) & P(X_{t'} = x_d | X_t = x_2) & \cdots & P(X_{t'} = x_d | X_t = x_d)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this correct? Are there any other possible forms for this stochastic matrix?

**Question 2.** What is an example of an *indivisible process*? If both $\Gamma_{t:r}$ and $\Gamma_{t:s}\Gamma_{s:r}$ correctly map every $\mathbb P(X_r)$ to $\mathbb P(X_t)$, how can they be different?